# Safari 7 on Desktop Displays Mobile Media Queries

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, safari7

I'm having a very strange issue. A site i'm developing displays perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, IE8+, Safari 6 and below but in Safari 7 on Mavericks ONLY the website displays as it should on a mobile site.

This is the site: http://dev.silvercreativegroup.com/op/

I've tested this on 3 machines running Mavericks with the same result. I've tried changing the DOCTYPE but that did not do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: It turns out the following media queries were doing it, I still have no idea why so if anyone has any insight I'd be interested to understand why it happened.

    `@media only screen and (width: 584px),
    @media only screen and (width: 420px) {
         /* CSS was here */
    }`

Made ONLY Safari 7 on Mavericks display the website as a mobile site.

Comment: I'm no expert on media query syntax, but that doesn't look well formed to me anyhow. It looks contradictory and also looks like it wouldn't do much. It's better to use `min-width` and `max-width`.